# Passing any concrete class for a wildcard in a generic class gives error. Why?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have a method for sorting a List of composite Entry objects with Integer key and any type for the value. It has the following signature:

```
static void bucketSort(List<Entry<Integer, ?>> list, int n)
{
    //some code
}
```

Where the entry interface is as follows:

```
interface Entry<K, V> {
    K getKey(); //returns key stored in this entry
    V getValue(); //returns the value stored in this entry
}
```

However, even though, in my understanding any object can be passed for the "?", this code generates a compile error ("cannot resolve method") in the second line:

```
List<Entry<Integer, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
bucketSort(list, 100);
```

Also, this code gives no error:

```
List<Entry<Integer, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
bucketSort(list, 100);
```

Can anyone please help me understand why this is? And also, what is the recommended way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Take a look at [PECS](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics-pecs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use wildcard for `Entry` object also, wildcard represents an unknown type. In the above code you defined `Entry<Integer, ?>` entry with key `Integer` and value `unknown type`, But in the same way you have to say for entry objects in `List`

```
static void bucketSort(List<? extends Entry<Integer, ?>> list, int n)
{
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets rid of the error, but can you explain why or direct to a source that explains this?